# Mongo error in Golang FieldPath field names may not contain '.'. Consider using $getField or $setField

Tags: mongodb, go

I have such a request in mongo shell and it works fine:

```
db.MonthlySeries.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "series": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$series",
          "as": "a",
          "cond": {
                "$gte": [
                  "$$a.date",
                  "2019"
                ]
              }
          }
        }
      },
    "_meta.symbol": "someSymbol"
    }
  }
])
```

There is also a similar request in golang:

```
bson.M{"$project": bson.M{
            "series": bson.M{
                "$filter": bson.M{
                    "input": "$series",
                    "as":    "a",
                    "cond": bson.M{
                        "$gte": bson.M{
                            "&&a.date": "2019",
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
            "_meta.symbol": t.Get("symbol"),
        },
    }
```

I can't figure out what this error is related to, I don't think mango driver in go doesn't support nested fields.
Maybe someone has already encountered this problem and knows how to solve it

Comment: Is that `&&` supposed to be `$$`?

Comment: `"$gte": [ "$$a.date", "2019" ]`  -  you may want use [bson.A](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.7.2/bson#A) instead of `bson.M`. Also, take a look at using `bson.D`. Note the usage of these bson types: [Work with BSON](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/go/current/fundamentals/bson/).

Comment: @Joe thanks, I didn't notice it, but now I get this error: Unrecognized expression '$$a.date'